# Buildozer adding my packages

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

> I developed an app in python3.5.2 gui work by using kivy and it's working fine in pc but not in android

I have my package (name=PassStorage) consist 3 mudules (name=accounts.py,data.py,keyandnick.py) that are connected to each other by compositions and in main.py i am importing these mudules

```
from PassStorage.account import Account
from PassStorage.data import Data
from PassStorage.keyandnick import KeyAndNick
```

this is working fine in pc but after

```
buildozer android debug run
```

app is not working in android.

> What do i need to do in buildozer.spec ?

Comment: use `buildozer android run logcat` to get error what it crashes on android, if you can't find the solution from there, post the relevant part of the log here.

Comment: Anyone got a solution? I have a similar problem. logcat just says package missing

Comment: I have solved it but just don't remember how. Can you tell me r u using what packages are you using of python?

Comment: @user378625 I have had similar problems. See my questions and answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759679/how-do-you-create-a-kivy-apk-from-a-package and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786351/how-can-i-import-an-package-into-a-kivy-app-using-buildozer