# How do you create a kivy apk from a package?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have a simple python/kivy package from which I wish to create an android APK using Buildozer. The package from the root is organised as:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── kivy_test-0.1-debug.apk
│   └── myapp-0.1-debug.apk
├── buildozer.spec
├── __init__.py
└── kivy_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    └── source
        ├── main.py
        └── version.py
```

The module main.py is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

from version import VERSION

root = Builder.load_string('''
<MainFrame>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Hola mundo!'
        Label:
            text: root.version
''')

class MainFrame(Screen):
    version = 'Version: %s' % VERSION
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

version.py is

```
__all__ = 'VERSION'

VERSION = '0.0.2'
```

and `_`*main`_`*.py is

```
from .source.main import BasicApp

def main():
    BasicApp().run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem that I have is that when I run the module by typing

```
python -m kivy_app
```

in the root directory I need to have  the line

```
from .version import VERSION
```

in main.py (note there is '.' before version).

On the other hand, when I build the android apk from the root directory the buildozer.spec uses the line:

```
# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = ./kivy_app/source
```

and of course it is invoking the lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     BasicApp().run()
```

in main.py.

In this case the module is treated as if it is not in a package and so needs the line:

```
from version import VERSION
```

(In this case no '.' before version in the import statement)

How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this conflict it to copy `_`*main`_`*.py to main.py and to replace the line:

```
from .source.main import BasicApp
```

with:

```
from source.main import BasicApp
```

In buildozer.spec replace:

```
source.dir = ./kivy_app/source
```

with:

```
source.dir = ./kivy_app
```

The tree is now:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── kivy_test-0.1-debug.apk
│   └── myapp-0.1-debug.apk
├── buildozer.spec
├── __init__.py
└── kivy_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── source
        ├── main.py
        └── version.py
```