# How can I import an package into a Kivy app using buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have created a kivy app in package using the structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── myapp-0.1-debug.apk
├── buildozer.spec
└── kivy_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── source
        └── kivy_app.py
```

I wish to use some features contained in another package that I have written:

```
.
└── python_pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    └── source
        └── version.py
```

The module version.py contains:

```
VERSION = '0.0.1'
```

When I insert the line:

```
from python_pkg import VERSION
```

into kivy_app.py, it works perfectly in kivy on the PC.

I have added python_pkg to the requirements line in buildozer.spec.

I can build an APK, but the application will not run on Android. The logcat output at the point of failure is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VERSION' from 'python_pkg' (/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/python_pkg/__init__.pyc)
```

The `_`*init`_`*.py module in python_pkg has the line:

```
from python_pkg.source.version import VERSION
```

How must arrange the setup up so that it works?

Comment: Simplest way: just copy python_pkg into your app (a symlink may work). More complicated way: create a setup.py for python_pkg and pass the filepath into the p4a requirements the same way you would with pip, if pip supports that.

Comment: @inclement That works.  I have created an answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @inclement I have a solution. I have created a symlink to python_pkg and placed it in the kivy_app directory. The structure of the application is now

```
.
├── bin
│   └── myapp-0.1-debug.apk
├── buildozer.spec
└── kivy_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── python_pkg -> /home/jeff/projects/kivy_pkg/python_pkg/python_pkg
    └── source
        └── kivy_app.py
```

The element python_pkg is not needed in the requirements line in buildozer.spec and I have removed it.